# SQL error in create table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Every time I try to run the create.sql file I have, it says there is a syntax error near "buy_price". The rest of the tables work fine, though.

```
create table Item (itemID string PRIMARY KEY, 
    name string, 
    currently string, 
    buy_price string, 
    first_bid string, 
    started string, 
    ends string, 
    userID string references User, 
    description string, 
    constraint ch_buy_price check buy_price >= first_bid,
    constraint );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using??

Comment: 1. What database is this for? 2. The code seems incomplete as the last contraint is missing or empty?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQLite accepts _string_ as a data type and treats it as numeric according to the rules for affinity: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity unless I'm misinterpreting the docs.

Comment: @jpw: I noticed that SQLite accepts `string`as a data type although it's not specified as one (_very_ strange behaviour in my opinion though)

Answer (score 2):

The check constraint needs to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
create table item 
(
  itemid        string primary key,
  name          string,
  currently_    string,
  buy_price     string,
  first_bid     string,
  started       string,
  ends          string,
  userid        string references user,
  description   string,
  constraint chk_buy_price check (buy_price >= first_bid) --<< here
);
```

You also have an additional `constraint` at the end which needs to be removed.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting the error because you can not refer first_bid(table column) in check constraint(**Column check constraint cannot reference other column**).If you want to have a check for this use triggers.

Comment: This would depend on the database used. It would work fine with SQLite and MSSQL for example.

Comment: I am not sure about SQLite but string datatype does not belongs to MSSQL.

Comment: No, MSSQL does not have any type named _string_ but the assertion about the constraint is still incorrect, which was my point. SQLite accepts `string` as a type and lets you define the constraint in the way done in the question. See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ebcbc

Comment: The check constraint would be valid for MS SQL Server as well (if correctly enclosed in parentheses)